# select values from xml field sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Just looking at my XML field, my rows look like this:

```
<ReturnData>
  <Header>
    <Type>SAM</Type>
  </Header>
<ReturnData>
```

I need to get ReturnData/Header/Type value. Please help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int, XML xml )
Insert Into @YourTable values 
(1,'<ReturnData><Header><Type>SAM</Type></Header></ReturnData>')

Select A.ID
      ,Type = A.XML.value('(ReturnData/Header/Type)[1]','varchar(100)')
 From @YourTable A
```

Returns

```
ID  Type
1   SAM
```